# Listview 's setOnItemLongClickListener does not shows a AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

There is a confusion in developing an app that, i have listed out SQLite data in a list. i want to make it work like, as user long clicks on it it should show a alert dialog with 4-5 items. But it fails. if anyone have idea about it ? so please direct me to it.

I have used this code , but doesnot works....

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener ( new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick ( AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"India", "US", "UK","Australia"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new    AlertDialog.Builder(CustomerConView.this);

        builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog with ListView");

        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {                                 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

});
```

Thanks....

Comment: post Code and errors if any. No idea without those two..

Comment: how it fails? app crash?? if yes then please post logcat

Comment: this code works for edittext's but i am unable to find sol. for list view...

Answer (score 1):

Use the method: [registerForContextMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29)

You have to call it on the onCreate of the activity and you have to implement the method "[onCreateContextMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu%28android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo%29)".

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("postiton", String.valueOf(position));
        //switch(position)
        //{
        //case 0:
        if(position==0)
        {
            if(Session.getActiveSession()==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must login first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Update Status");

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_status, null);
                //dialog.
                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Update Status", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ButtonId) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        UpdateStatus();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        }

        //case 1:
        if(position==1) 
        {

            if(Session.getActiveSession()==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must login first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Upload Photo");

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_photo, null);

                Button browse = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.browsePhotoButton);
                browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                    }
                });

                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Upload Photo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ButtonId) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        publishStory(image);
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        }

        if(position==2)
        {
            if(Session.getActiveSession()==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must login first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent friendsActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Friends.class);
                startActivity(friendsActivity);
            }
        }


    }
```

See this i am also showing dialog on listview item click.

The problem you are not setting view of alert dialog to show something you should assign it some layout to show in alert dialog. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

use this , this may help you . . . . .

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem aItem) 
    {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) aItem.getMenuInfo();
        switch (aItem.getItemId()) 
        {
            case 0:
                try 
                {
                    // your code 
                }
                catch (Exception ewe) 
                {
                    Log.e("Exception",""+ewe)
                }       
                break;

            case 1:
                           ................ for all your cases

            break;  
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Application Context does not work in other class

so write classname.this

> e.g myservice.this

where myservice is my class name